# google sheet vlookup from another sheet (same doc) #N/A

Tags: google-sheets-formula

i've been trying to use the function vlookup on a google sheet to find from another sheet the image link to a name.

Problem, the function return #N/A. So i've tested with a more simplier version of my table and it wortk perfectly.

I can't understand why my test on my sheet "Test 1" and "Test 2" work and not on my sheet "Porject 1" and "Project 2" not.

Here is a link of my gsheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HmyzX394fgbCt4ukh5nbIX7QPzLpjCYIORxl6ebuQbg/edit?usp=sharing

Here is an exemple of the vlookup i use :

=VLOOKUP($B2;'Project 2'!$A$2:$B$30;1;FALSE) (return #N/A)

and this is the version i used on my Test sheet :

=VLOOKUP($A2;'Test 2'!$A$2:$C$4;2;FALSE) (do return the correcte image)

Comment: Vlookup always search lookup value to first column but your your lookup values in 2nd column in `Project 2` sheet. Change data setup or use index/match functions.

Comment: This is a bit weird but thanks for the help